# Excel Ribbon Not Switching To Tab When Opening

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I have an Excel 2013 workbook and am trying to switch a custom tab when the it is opened.

I have the following CustomUIx.xml entries:

CustomUI.xml

```
<customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
        <tab id="CustomHFG" label="Custom" insertAfterMso="TabDeveloper">

        </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

CustomUI14.xml

```
<customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
        <tab id="CustomHFG" label="Custom" insertAfterMso="TabDeveloper">

        </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

and the folloing VBA code in a module:

```
Option Explicit
Public ribRibbon As IRibbonUI

Public Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set ribRibbon = ribbon
    ribRibbon.ActivateTab ("CustomHFG")
End Sub
```

When I open the workbook, it does not activate the 'CustomHFG' tab.  I believe the RibbonOnLoad sub is being called as I have a `debug.asset false` statement after the `ribRibbon.ActivateTab ("CustomHFG")` line and it breaks here so I'm sure ActivateTab is being called.

Any suggestions as to why this is not activating the tab on open?

Thanks

Comment: That's strange. I do not see anything wrong with the code...

Comment: Can you test it in a new workbook?

Comment: I have code similar to this working on another workbook; the only difference being the tab ID was different...

Comment: Nothing wrong with the Tab Id. Like I said it works for me. Try this.. Create a new .xlsm file and paste the VBA code. save it as tester.xlsm in desktop. Use CustomUI editor to put the above xml code. save and close. Now open the workbook. Does it work for the new workbook?

Comment: do you get any ribbon UI errors in Excel?

Comment: I see two files with a custom UI. Did you try to use a single custom UI xml file?

Comment: Fixed this.  I copied and pasted everything above in to a fresh workbook and it all works as expected.  I suspect Excel got itself in to a muddle somewhere along the lines... Thanks for the suggestions :)