# Workbook_Open - how to combine one and more codes?

Tags: excel, vba

> Before asking a question I reviewed many options and nothing helped me!

I have in `PERSONAL.XLSB` some code. This VBA Saves and closes all books after clicking on the red cross. It works without any problems:

```
Private WithEvents xlApp As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set xlApp = Application
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub xlApp_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlApp.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Wb In xlApp.Workbooks
        Wb.Save 'Wb.Close True
    Next
    xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

I have another code which I want to work, when I open the Excel. Separately, this code works, but I do not know how to combine? This code opens my own tab on Ribbon:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    SendKeys "%BP{F6}", True
End Sub
```

Want to work when I open any Workbook.

Comment: so.... why not just combine them? You already have a Workbook_Open event, just add the code of one event to the other?

Comment: @TimStack Listen i try to put `SendKeys "%BP{F6}", True` before and after this string `Set xlApp = Application`. Not helped. Any idea?

Comment: Does the line even get executed? Put a break on it so you'll see if it does

Comment: Putting a break on `SendKeys` is never a good idea...Thought you could explain us why the SendKeys, is a shortcut for another procedure? Because you could call it directly instead using the shortcut like this.

Comment: Select `xlApp` from the left-hand dropdown at the top of the code pane. Then select `WorkbookOpen` from the right-hand dropdown. That will create a `xlApp_WorkbookOpen` handler that will run whenever a workbook is opened by the `xlApp` application instance... which is *exactly* how you should have come up with this `WorkbookBeforeClose` handler (or did you paste it from some website instead?)

Comment: What's that `SendKeys` for anyway? 99.99% of the time, you don't want to use `SendKeys`.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon ··· 1) I used this `xlApp_WorkbookOpen` not helps (i did paste it from [some website](http://www.cyberforum.ru/vba/thread561320.html#post13682495) instead). Can you post complete `code` with this action (maybe I'm doing something wrong)!? 2) 0Key Mathieu i see you have better option than `SendKeys`, please if so feel free to share with me, thx!

Comment: If we don't know what you're using SendKeys for, then how are we supposed to be able to suggest better alternatives?

Comment: Don't paste event handlers from websites. **Have the VBE create them for you**. That way you *know* they're understood as event handlers and not just some random useless procedure that isn't getting invoked by anything.

Comment: Ok, I think you're using `SendKeys` to activate a custom Ribbon tab. If that's the case then you could modify the XML to specify an `onload` handler and invoke the `IRibbonUI.ActivateTab` method - [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36113728/1188513)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon ··· It's me again. Thx for info but i have `Office 2019` This method I have tried and it does not work. About this there is [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56623675/vba-iribbonui-activatetab-not-working-in-office-2019).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Finally i solve this issue!

So if we have the codes then just shove inside and that's it:

```
Workbook_Open()
```

As for this line the problem was in the version of *Office*:

```
SendKeys "%БП{F6}"
```

In *Microsoft Office 365 2019* everything works well!